# How do I remap the keyboard shortcut for Gnome Do?

Tags: 11.04, unity, shortcut-keys, gnome-do

I am giving Unity a chance to win me over in Natty, but I admit I am a heavy Gnome Do user and Unity has remapped the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> keyboard shortcut to show the Unity Launcher.

I am not yet convinced with the new Unity Launcher and would like to keep using Gnome Do, at least until such time as I am convinced that the Unity launcher is as frictionless as Gnome Do.

Is it possible to remap it to Gnome Do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Install `compizconfig-settings-manager`

   ```
    sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `about:config` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the Unity configuration.
3. Either disable or bind the shortcut for *Key to show the launcher*  to another key:

   [image]
4. Now the <kbd>Super</kbd> key should open Gnome Do as before.

Answer (score -1):

You can also do:

1. System Settings
2. Type "Keyboard Shortcuts" in the search field.
3. Edit the shortcut key you want it be used for gnome-do. Add this shortcut key and bind it to "gnome-do" command.

Cheers :)